# How to run flutter app developed in AndroidStudio on iOS device?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I've developed a flutter app in AndroidStudio and everything is running perfect.

Now I want to display the app on iOS device. I see many similar questions which state that you have to have x-code, etc. setup on a MAC or virtually. Perfect, done all that setup, now, how do I get the AndroidStudio project into iOS IDE (VisualStudio?). I assume once I do that I just run like any other iOS app?

Seems that every flutter tutorial would have this but just don't see it when I google. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Flutter project is set up as follows:

```
Root directory
  - pubspec.yaml
  > lib
    - ... (dart files)
  > assets
    - ...
  > android
    - build.gradle
    > app
      - build.gradle
    > ...
  > ios
    - Runner.xcproject
    - Runner.xcworkspace * (this may not be there until running `pod install` or `flutter run`.
    - Podfile
    > ...
```

If you have XCode and everything set up properly on a mac, you should be able to run `flutter run` from the root directory and have it deploy to the device. You could possibly even do this from android studio, although I personally use IntelliJ so I cant verify that.

If you want to open the XCode project directly, you should actually get the option in IntelliJ (and possibly android studio) whenever you look at a swift or objc file. This is a fairly recent feature which has been introduced (as of June 2018).

Otherwise, you can directly open the Runner.xcworkspace file to open the XCode project. Running to a device should work from XCode after you've tried to build at least once with flutter (or you can run `pod install` in the iOS directory manually).

Comment: thanks, running 'flutter run' on MAC worked. For those Android devs like me trying flutter for the first time here is what I did:1. build app in AndroidStudio using Windows; 2. on MAC install flutter, and xcode; 3. signup for Apple dev (I did free option for now); 4. on command line in project directory type 'flutter run'; 5. I was able to run on both an emulator as well as a phone!

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straight forward. You open the root of the flutter project with Android Studio. You should also open your_project/ios with xcode to set the signing keys, dependencies and other stuff with a nice ui.

Important is that when you run flutter doctor it don't have any errors. If it has, fix those first.

Also when I used Android Studio I sometimes encountered a bug where the project would not run on the emulator. In such cases try to run your code in xcode first and the flutter clean.

[Here](https://flutter.io/ios-release/) is a nice reference for building on mac.